# Two dimensional array processing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I've a two-dimensional array of integer values. I want to process the array in the most efficient way. The processing logic is:

if summary[row][col] is greater than summary[col][row], then summary[row][col] -= summary[col][row] and vice versa. If both are equal, then make both positions zero. Basically, calculating the absolute difference between the two positions.

Here is the logic I built. Is there a cleaner, efficient way to do this using Array functions?

```
  row_ix = 0
  summary.each do |row|
    col_ix = 0
    row.each do |row_to_col_amt|
      if row_ix == col_ix
        col_ix += 1
        next
      end
      col_to_row_amt = summary[col_ix][row_ix]
      if row_to_col_amt >  col_to_row_amt
        summary[row_ix][col_ix] -= col_to_row_amt
        summary[col_ix][row_ix] = 0
      elsif row_to_col_amt <  col_to_row_amt
        summary[col_ix][row_ix] -= row_to_col_amt
        summary[row_ix][col_ix] = 0
      else
        summary[row_ix][col_ix] = 0
        summary[col_ix][row_ix] = 0
      end
      col_ix += 1
    end
    row_ix += 1
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question.

The `ary` should be a square matrix, so there is a 1 to 1 relation between (x,y) and (y,x). Since on the diagonal `ary(x, y) == ary(y, x)` is always true, I left it untouched (or its easy to set it to `0`).

So, given the matrix:

```
ary = 
      [
        [1,  5,  5,  1, 5],
        [1,  1,  1,  1, 1],
        [1,  1,  1,  1, 1 ],
        [1,  1,  1,  1, 1 ],
        [5,  10, 10,  1, 10]
      ]
```

Let's defina a method which return the upper triangle indexes, excluded the diagonal:

```
def top_triangle_idxs(ary)
  n = ary.size - 1
  res = []
  (0..n).each do |m|
    (1..n).each do |n|
      res << [m,n] unless m == n || m > n
    end
  end
  res
end
```

So, for that case:

```
idxs = top_triangle_idxs(ary)
#=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Now, lets iterate over `idxs` doing the logic:

```
idxs.each do |x,y|
  ary[x][y] -= ary[y][x] if ary[x][y] > ary[y][x]
  ary[y][x] -= ary[x][y] if ary[x][y] < ary[y][x]
  ary[x][y] = ary[y][x] = 0 if ary[x][y] == ary[y][x]
end
```

The result:

```
ary.each(&method(:p))
# [1, 4, 4, 0, 0]
# [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
# [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
# [0, 9, 9, 0, 10]
```

---

You can get the same result using [Enumerable#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) and [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), but building a new matrix:

```
res = ary.each_with_index.with_object(Array.new(ary.size) { [] }) do |(row, x), new_ary|
  row.each_with_index do |e, y|
    new_ary[x][y] = e
    new_ary[x][y] = e - ary[y][x] if ary[x][y] > ary[y][x]
    new_ary[x][y] = 0 if e == ary[y][x] && x != y
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, it is a square matrix. Thanks for a solution. I'm wondering if there is a simpler solution involving array functions such reduce, map, etc. so that the custom code can be reduced